# How to obtain a network completely connected in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network, linear-referencing

I have a vector of lines, in which some of them are isolated from the rest of the lines, but I need that every line is connected to at least another one, so as to obtain a unique connected path.

This is a part of the network, where there are isolated (black) lines:[image: Disconnected_network]

I would like to know if there is a tool that could connect automatically those lines in order to obtain a unique path (for example, as I shown with the evident handmade red lines)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the **Join multiple lines** plugin which allows you to select multiple lines and it will automatically create a new line from the  existing vertices. You can install this from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins
```

---

**Example**:

Select your disconnected lines (highlighted in yellow):

[image: Disconnected lines]

Then click the icon for the Join multiple lines plugin:

[image: New connected line]